# UNIQUE Constraint On Combination of Two Column Values

Tags: mysql, node.js

Wasn't sure how to word the question so my bad if it sounds weird.

I have a table in my database called `friendRequests` with the the following columns: `id`, `sender_id`, `recipient_id`, and `status`. How can I make sure that no other row has duplicate `recipient_id` and `sender_id` values?

So for example, if I had a row in the table with the following values: `(1, 4, 6, 0)`, how can I make sure that no other row has a `sender_id` of 4 and a `recipient_id` of 6 **AND** that no other row has a `sender_id` of 6 and a `recipient_id` of 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `same relations` - use a unique constraint on `<sender, receiver>`.

The inverse relation `<receiver, sender>` however will be possible, cause it's different ids for the unique key constraint.

To handle this (using a uniqe key constraint), you have to add another column, let's call it `friendship` - There, you'll add a unique key constraint, and insert the users ids, concatenated, BUT ORDERED:

I.e. If a user `3` sends a friend request to `10`, you'll insert `3-10` to that column. If the invitation goes from `10` to `3`, you'll add `3-10` as well.

This way, you can keep track of WHO initiated the friendship (`sender_column=3`, `receiver-column=10`) but also ensure that there is no backwards invite (`friendship=3-10` already exists)

So that's something like

```
INSERT INTO friendships(sender, receiver, friendship) VALUES(3,10,"3-10");
or vice versa:
INSERT INTO friendships(sender, receiver, friendship) VALUES(10,3,"3-10");
```

One of both constraints will avoid the insertion if the friendship has been already requested. (Actually the second constraint would be sufficent for any case, first 2 columns would only allow to determine the active and passive part of the friendship.)

Comment: I'd argue its worst to use a string-like field, and just create another two columns with a UNIQUE constraint on both of them.

Comment: I was actually thinking about doing something like the second constraint but wasn't exactly sure how it would work/how to implement it. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @Evert That wouldn't help at all, as there would be another set of "reverse-relation" possible. I.e. with 4 columns, you could insert `1|2|2|1` but also `2|1|1|2`. You NEED a combination of BOTH unique-ids reflected in ONE column to cover this, cause every "pair" of columns could have a inverse insert which is not covered by the unique-pair-constraint.

Comment: @Evert No matter the "count" of unique column pairs: Assume 5 pairs, so 10 columns - there is exactly one combination reflecting the reverse insert not covered by the constraint(s): `1010101010` vs `0101010101`.

Comment: @dognose I would propose sorting the ids, so that if theres 2 columns, the first column would always have the lowest number. You still need to do that in your proposal too, so why not do that in 2 columns.

Comment: No, I would propose adding 2 extra columns, instead of 1 extra column that's always sorted. 2 extra columns that use the right columntype is better than a VARCHAR column type in your proposal.

Comment: @Evert Can you outline any "Problems" with a varchar column for identification of a certain row?

Comment: @Evert doing this in two columns (smaller_id, greater_id) will throw away the information who "requested" the friendship.

Comment: @dognose, I'll try this explanation. You suggest 3 columns (int, int, varchar), I suggest 4 (int, int, int, int). Better?

Comment: As to why VARCHAR is worse... you should be able to answer this question yourself. Why not use VARCHAR for every field in a database?

Comment: @Evert Let me know, how your `(int, int, int, int)` approach turned out. As I mentioned: That wouldn't help at all, as there would be another set of "reverse-relation" possible. I.e. with 4 columns, you could insert 1|2|2|1 but also 2|1|1|2. You NEED a combination of BOTH unique-ids reflected in ONE column to cover this, cause every "pair" of columns could have a inverse insert which is not covered by the unique-pair-constraint... If `int` (for a key) is always better than `varchar` - then why does mysql allow `varchar-primary.keys`?

Comment: @Evert `int`-keys tend to be faster - but that doesn't mean, that you can solve each and everything by using `int`-keys.

Comment: @dognose, just tested it. It worked great =). The reason varchar primary keys exist, is because not everything is a number.

Comment: And just so we're clear. My suggestion to use 2 ints works because I'm also suggesting that for the 2 ints they should also be ordered, just like your own suggestion with varchar. The end-result is the same, but better.

Comment: @Evert okay, having 4 Ints, with the first pair showing the "invite direction" and the second pair showing the "relationship" (ordered insert) would work as well, right. Can't tell out of the box if this would be faster than concatenated strings - but guess for anything smaller than 20 Million records, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Thanks for the acknowledgement. You might be right, but generally it's considered a good idea to use the right column type if you can. However, with small databases you could probably also get away with making literally every field a VARCHAR.

Comment: I thought more about it, and realized it could be shorter. You can do it with 3 ints. 2 for the 'relationship' and just use 1 for the 'invite direction'. The second one in the invite direction can then be inferred because it's the one that's missing.

Comment: @Evert Allways acknowledging "better" solutions, SO is no contest (at least for me).. the "3 int solution" will work as well, if you move another check into the "code-part": i.e. if (3,10,3) exists, (10,3,10) isn't allowed as well. However since sorting ALSO happens before Insert, it would work out as well and maybe be the most efficent solution, when it comes down to query the data. little more effort upon insertion, but that shouldn't happen that often.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a unique index on the table.

```
create unique index sender_recipient
on friendRequest (sender_id, récipient_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

What I'm hearing is, if user A invites user B, you don't want to create a new record for user B inviting using A.

I don't think it's possible to enforce a constraint like that, except perhaps through the use of triggers, which I would probably not recommend. I would suggest to try and enforce this in your application.

Comment: So, I should just run a query checking if a friend request already exists between both users and create one if there isn't? Is that really the best way to do it?

Comment: @NatividadAlvarez I think the suggestion by dognose to use a separate field(s) might be a good alternative.

Comment: I personally believe it would be better to handle duplicate records with SQL because nesting queries like that, especially when they're callback functions, can make my code more error prone and unnecessarily complex. That's why I was asking for a SQL solution.